# No se actualiza el HTML de un elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy intentando recuperar el HTML de un elemento tal y como está al dar click al botón.
Pongo un snippet de ejemplo

```js
$( () => {
  $( document ).on('click', 'button', function(){
    const html = $('div').html();
    console.log( html );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Guardar</button>
</div>
```

Si escribo algo en el input por ejemplo *Hola Mundo* al dar click yo esperaría el HTML de la siguiente forma

```
<div>
  <input type="text" value="Hola Mundo">
  <button>Guardar</button>
</div>
```

Puesto que se supone que el DOM cambió al agregar texto al input, sin embargo sigue apareciendo sin cambios. He buscado el cambio en diferentes índices del selector sin embargo ninguno tiene la actualización, he buscando en

```
$('div')[0].outerHTML
$('div')[0].innerHTML
$('div').clone().html()
$('div').html()
```

Sin resultado alguno. ¿Cómo podré sacar esa información?

Comment: ¿Has probado a borrar el caché y las cookies del navegador web?

Comment: El atributo `value` de los `<input type="text">` sirve para otorgar al elemento un valor inicial. ¿Qué quiere decir? Que no tiene nada que ver con lo que luego obtenemos de él tras pedir su *valor*  con **Javascript**. La prueba es que podemos tener un `<input type="text" value="Hola Mundo">`, borrar el valor inicial para rellenarlo con otro texto y al pedir su *valor* obtener el nuevo texto, sin verse en ningún momento el **HTML** modificado por esta acción. Si no existe cambio en el **HTML** no vas a poder capturar el elemento de la manera que tú quieres.

Comment: Entiendo, pero no es lo que quiero conseguir. Lo que he puesto en el snippet es un ejemplo. En realidad quiero capturar todo el HTML de una tabla de 100 registros y 6 columnas, cada uno con valores modificados. Vaya lo que yo hice es para ejemplificar lo que necesito sacar, no que eso es realmente el problema. Igual agradezco tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

no sè si esta bien hacer eso. Pero en la función pondrías primero un valor al atributo **value** como lo siguiente.

```
 $( () => {
  $( document ).on('click', 'button', function(){
    //colocamos el valor como attributo
    $('input').attr('value',$('input').val());
    //luego mostramos
    const html = $('div').html();
    console.log( html );
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias Clinton, pero no es lo que estoy buscando, no quiero obtener los valores por separado, quiero obtener el HTML actual del selector.